# Javascript colors and tables?

Tags: javascript, html, web-safe-colors

I'm doing revision in preparation for my Web Development exam, and came across this question:[image]

My answer:

```
    function pallete() {
        var components = ["00", "33", "66", "99", "CC", "FF"];
        var context = document.body;
        var tab = document.createElement('table');
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                var trow = document.createElement('tr');
                for (f = 0; f < 6; f++) {
                    var thead = document.createElement('th');
                    thead.innerHTML = "#" + components[i] + components[j] + components[f];
                    thead.style.color = components[i] + components[j] + components[f];
                    trow.appendChild(thead);
                }
                tab.appendChild(trow);
            }
        }
        context.appendChild(tab);
    }
```

I tested the code on the browser, but nothing is coming up! I think my logic is perfect though... Not sure what went wrong here. Please give me any pointers, thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Oh, nothing appears on the page at all, a blank page.

Comment: Is this your complete code? Do you actually call your function?

Comment: @georg yes, the HTML code is the one in the question, haven't changed anything in it.

Comment: I copied your code as-is into a fiddle, and it definitely displays all of the required text: https://jsfiddle.net/yhyp0eye/ - I just had to add `window.onload=palette` because jsfiddle doesn't like you messing with the body element, but it should work in your version. It doesn't set the colours because you need to add `"#"` at the beginning of the colour code: https://jsfiddle.net/yhyp0eye/1/ - Or if you want to set the background colours: https://jsfiddle.net/yhyp0eye/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help nnnnnn! Yep everything finally works now, thanks to everyone that helped me! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example with

- declaration block at top of function
- `document.createElement`
- `td` instead of `th`
- `innerHTML` as assignment
- `td.style.backgroundColor` instead of `td.style.color`
- assignment to color needs `#` in front of color values, like `#003366`

```js
function pallete() {
    var components = ["00", "33", "66", "99", "CC", "FF"],
        context = document.body,
        tab = document.createElement('table'),
        trow, td,
        i, j, f;

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            trow = document.createElement('tr');
            for (f = 0; f < 6; f++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerHTML = "#" + components[i] + components[j] + components[f];
                td.style.backgroundColor = "#" + components[i] + components[j] + components[f];
                trow.appendChild(td);
            }
            tab.appendChild(trow);
        }
    }
    context.appendChild(tab);
}
```

```html
<body onload="pallete();"></body>
```

Comment: Why didn't the OP's code work? I mean, I know why the colours didn't work, but all of the th elements should've been created with the right text in them - this is his function called via `window.onload = pallete`: https://jsfiddle.net/yhyp0eye/

Comment: the `thead.style.color` assignment needs `#` infront and it does change the color of the font and not the background.

Comment: Yes, as I said, I know why the colours didn't work, but creation of the text should've worked fine *and did* when I copied his code into a fiddle. But the OP said he's getting a blank page.

Comment: Hmm your code works on stackoverflow, but doesn't work on fiddle haha. Probs difference between SF and fiddle, ill give it a try on a new document, i'll let you know the results, thank you!

Comment: Alright it does work on fiddle my bad haha and I tried it on my HTML document, it also works! Thank you Nina!

Answer (score 2):

Use document.createElement() instead of context.createElement(). Also assign value to thead.innerHTML instead of using it as a set function

```
function pallete() {
    var components = ["00", "33", "66", "99", "CC", "FF"];
    var context = document.body;
    var tab = document.createElement('table');
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            var trow = document.createElement('tr');
            for (f = 0; f < 6; f++) {
                var thead = document.createElement('th');
                thead.innerHTML = "#" + components[i] + components[j] + components[f];
                thead.style.color = components[i] + components[j] + components[f];
                trow.appendChild(thead);
            }
            tab.appendChild(trow);
        }
    }
    context.appendChild(tab);
}
```

Another suggestion will be to use 'td' instead of 'th'

Comment: use `thead.style.backgroundColor = '#'` + ... instead of `thead.style.color` and `var i, j, f;`

Comment: @NinaScholz I did what you said and it doesn't work either :(